# How can I SUM() SQL roq\w

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have tried :

```
select DISTINCT(campaign_name), count(DISTINCT id) as account_level,
    (SELECT MAX(v) FROM 
        (VALUES (point_reward1) , (point_reward2) , (point_reward3) , (point_reward4) , (point_reward5) , (point_reward6) , (point_reward7) , (point_reward8)) max_point(v))
    AS total_point
from reward_redemption
where
campaign_status !='REJECT_CAMPAIGN'
and is_reported = 0
and campaign_status is not null
AND campaign_name = 'Rwdrdm201049'
group by campaign_name
, point_reward1, point_reward2, point_reward3, point_reward4, point_reward5, point_reward6, point_reward7, point_reward8;
```

Result :

```
campaign_name|account_level|total_point|
-------------|-------------|-----------|
Rwdrdm201049 |            1|      30011|
Rwdrdm201049 |            1|      30018|
```

Question :
How can I make the result to one row become like this?

```
campaign_name|account_level|total_point|
-------------|-------------|-----------|
Rwdrdm201049 |            2|      60029|
```

Edit:
this is my data looks like

```
id                     |campaign_name|point_reward1|point_reward2|point_reward3|point_reward4|point_reward5|point_reward6|point_reward7|point_reward8|campaign_status|is_reported|
-----------------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|---------------|-----------|
RWD00V1o2_0W7x0d5N799nY|Rwdrdm201049 |        10018|        20018|        30018|             |             |             |             |             |NO_RESPONSE    |          0|
RWD7001a2c0Y7r0e557i9Ug|Rwdrdm201049 |        10011|        20011|        30011|             |             |             |             |             |NO_RESPONSE    |          0|
```

Comment: Have you considered using `SUM`? Also you should show us what your data looks like *before* your attempt as well. Otherwise we have the guess reverse engineer it.

Comment: If you group by campaign_name, then attempting to apply distinct is pointless as grouping will generate 1 row per name. But adding the additional columns causes multiple rows to appear since you are telling the engine to generate one row for every tuple in your group by clause.

Comment: @Larnu thanks, hmm so what I can use to make the result like I want?. Btw, I already add the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per campaign, that should be the only column in the `GROUP BY`.  To facilitate this, you should use `apply`:

```
select rr.campaign_name, count(DISTINCT rr.id) as account_level,
       v.total_point
from reward_redemption rr cross apply
     (select max(point) as  total_point
      from (values (rr.point_reward1), (rr.point_reward2) , (rr.point_reward3), (rr.point_reward4), (rr.point_reward5) , (rr.point_reward6), (rr.point_reward7), (rr.point_reward8)
           ) v(point)
     ) v
where rr.campaign_status <> 'REJECT_CAMPAIGN' and
      rr.is_reported = 0 and
      rr.campaign_status is not null and
      rr.campaign_name = 'Rwdrdm201049'
group by rr.campaign_name, v.total_point
```